# Looking for Flag to disable Auth in JSF web.xml

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, authentication, web.xml

I'm searching a simple true/false flag in the web.xml for enabling or disabling the authentication in JSF.

The situation:

I have a web.xml with the following code for authentication:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>${test.auth}</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Tester</description>
    <role-name>Tester</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Test-Server-Access</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Test-Server-Access</web-resource-name>
      <description/>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <description>Tester Access</description>
      <role-name>Tester</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <description>HTTPS Login</description>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

everything is working as expected and pretty good for my purpose. But theres one thing left.
As you can see I want to fill in a param (`<auth-method>${test.auth}</auth-method>`) and this is working pretty well too. But now I need something like a flag for disabling the whole auth mechanism with such a param. I already tried it with `<auth-method>NONE</auth-method>` but I think the system is still expecting a user in the role Tester.

So how to disable the whole auth mechanism without commenting it out?

Context:

I have different environments for my application:

- Development on the local machine
- Test-Server
- Production-Server

Now I want that authentication only happens on the Test-Server. For that I use maven-profiles for

- Development -> no profile
- Test-Server -> test profile
- Production-Server -> production profile

To achieve that different behavior I filter the web.xml through maven and insert values at build-time e.g. `<auth-method>${test.auth}</auth-method>`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "solved" the problem by setting the url-pattern to a never used site. Thats not nice but it works for now :/.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Tester</description>
    <role-name>Tester</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Test-Server-Access</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Test-Server-Access</web-resource-name>
      <description/>
      <url-pattern>${test.url}</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <description>Tester Access</description>
      <role-name>Tester</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <description>HTTPS Login</description>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I would appreciate a cleaner solution if theres any.